# How many connections can TCP_WRAPPERS handle?

Tags: linux

As we know that TCP_WRAPPERS is a good way of security on linux/unix system, to disallow or allow remote user to connect to the specific services. Assume that if there have a large number of disallowed connections to the server configured with TCP_WRAPPERS, how many concurrent connections the TCP_WRAPPERS could handle?

Does it depend on TCP_WRAPPERS or Linux/Unix itself?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the hardware available and how you've configured the underlying OS - tcpd runs in user-space.

(NB if you have long lists of hosts, then do make sure you've got NIS maps set up for them).